# Consulta al aplicar estilo CSS en PHP

Tags: html, ccs

Estoy trabajando con CSS y HTML, no soy experto en este tema y por eso hago esta consulta. Descargue un proyecto en PHP de una pagina para aplicarlo en mi sistema. Tengo mi hoja de estilo personal de CSS y tuve que cargar una hoja de estilo de Bootstrap. Al hacer esto se modifica el estilo de mi pagina.
Mi consulta es para que sirve ?1.3 y como manejar cual hoja predomina sobre la otra, busque pero no he encontrado la respuesta. Muchas Gracias.

```
MI HOJA   / <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css?1.3" media="all">
BOOTSTRAP / <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">


 <head>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css?1.3" 
    media="all" >
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
   <title>Lista</title>
 </head>
```

Comment: Como tienes el css en las etiquetas en las que lo pones? Muestra el código.

Comment: Edite la pregunta

Comment: ¿Y si le quitas ese 1.3, qué pasa? Ese 1.3, es la versión del css en la que estás trabajando.

Comment: Cuando le quito el 1.3 se aplica el estilo de CSS y me desconfigura algunos aspectos de mi sistema.

Comment: Como tienes ese archivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba a invertir el orden de carga de tus hojas de estilo, ya que entiendo que necesitas bootstrap como framework para la estructura y que tu hoja personal lo que hace es modificar cuestiones meramente ornamentales. Para que prime el tuyo, "pisando" los estilos de bootstrap, el orden correcto debe ser:

BOOTSTRAP - `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">`

MI HOJA   - `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css?1.3" media="all">`

Esto se debe a que el orden de prioridad en cascada para la carga de archivos hace que el último "link" de css sea el que pesa sobre los previos, siempre en orden ascendente. Por delante de ellos estarían las etiquetas de  incluidas en el propio html y por encima incluso las que se añadan a las propias etiquetas de contenido (ejemplo `<p style="">XXX</p>`).

Comparto [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance) sobre como debe cargarse y aplicarse los estilos css por orden de prioridad en la carga.